# Printing from Excel file to Zebra printer

Tags: excel, vba, zebra-printers

I am very much of a beginner with VBA so forgive any sloppiness. I am looking for a macro or another way to print labels on a Zebra printer as soon as a value is inputted into a specific column in a spreadsheet. This is not designed to work for as soon as the value is inputted, I was just testing to see whether the printer prints a BARCODE which is the most important part of this, so I used the code below which I lifted from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-print-labels-from-excel.1082135/). The print area is the selected cell. It contains a 12-digit number to be printed as a barcode label:

```
Sub ZEBRA_LABEL()
Dim r As Long

With ActiveSheet
  With .PageSetup
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
  End With
For r = 5 To 20
    If Range("E" & r) <> "" Then          'the r values correspond with row numbers
      With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "$B$" & r & ":$E$" & r + 3
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut copies:=Range("A" & r).Value, collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    End With
    End If
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

However, this gives me an "Run time error 1004 - Application-defined or Object-defined error" (which makes sense because Cell.Value is not an object) and if I remove the `.Value` from the `ActiveSheet.PrintOut` statement the Zebra printer does not print a barcode but the appearance of the cell itself.

Anyone have any ideas about how to make this work? I tried almost every solution I could find online but nothing has worked for me

Comment: You are removing the `.Value` from the `Range()` call, not from `PrintOut` - and you shouldn't remove it if the cell `"A" & r` indeed contains the number of copies like it may appear from your code. Why do you think Excel would print anything *other* than the appearance of the cell itself? Did you put pass-through ZPL code somewhere inside the print area and format it with correct font and correct syntax to make that happen?

Comment: As I mentioned, I am a beginner. I am asking for *constructive* advice

Comment: You must provide way more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about the contents of your print area and the way you expect it to be printed in order to get a *constructive* advice.

Comment: The print area is the selected cell. It contains a 12-digit number to be printed as a barcode label

Comment: Your code says otherwise. Your print area is a 4x4 square, that is 16 cells, and you have not explained how you set up the barcode printing. The code you have "lifted" is a general purpose printout example that is not concerned with Zebras specifically. Have you set up something like [ZPL passthrough](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/how-to-pass-through-or-use-passthrough-for-printer-code-with-the-zebra-designer-driver.html), and if not, why do you expect the number to print as a barcode? What type of barcode even? Zebras support dozens of barcode types.

Comment: Sorry, the code I lifted is from someone who seemed to be looking to do the same thing. If you click the link you would see that it is concerned with Zebra printers. I was not aware of ZPL passthrough, it would have been nice to mention it nicely.